# Regular sequence and projective module

Tags: commutative-algebra, projective-module

Let $R$ be commutative ring and $x,y$ an $R$-regular sequence.

Then I know that $ R/(x)$ is not a projective $R$-module.

My question:

> Is $R^{2}/(x,y)R$ a projective $R$-module?

Comment: What do you mean by $R^2 / (x,y)R$?

Comment: @Youngsu Maybe a quotient module? ($(x,y)\in R^2$ and $(x,y)R$ can be the $R$-submodule of $R^2$ generated by $(x,y)$.)

Comment: @user26857: I also thought about that. But then isn't the answer no immediately?

Comment: @Youngsu Why is then the answer negative?

Comment: @user26857: If $(x,y) \subseteq R \subseteq R \oplus R$. Then $R^2 / (x,y)R \cong R / (x,y) \oplus R$. Therefore, $R^2/ (x,y)R$ is projective if and only if $R /(x,y)R$ is. But $R/(x,y)R$ is not projective over $R$.

Comment: @Youngsu I don't understand your play with $(x,y)$: sometimes it's an ideal, sometimes an element in $R^2$.

Comment: @user26857: You are right. It means the submodule not the ideal. But I think it is not true in general. Consider $R = k[[x,y]]$. From the following exact sequence $0 \to (x,y)R \to R^2 \to R^2/(x,y)R \to 0$, we see that $\operatorname{rank} R^2/(x,y)R = 1$. However the minimal number of generators for $R^2/ (x,y)R = 2$.